# Symfony 1.4 create route for pdf files

Tags: php, routes, symfony1

I want to create routing for following urls.

Everything begins `pdf` and ends with `.pdf`

```
site.com/en/pdf/aaa/bbb/file.pdf
site.com/pdf/aaa/bbb/file.pdf
site.com/pdf/file.pdf
...
```

My code is:

```
global_pdf:
  class: myRequestRoute
  url: /:sf_culture/pdf/*/*.pdf
  param: { module: pdf, action: showEmbed }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }
```

But it doesn't work.

How do that ?

Thank you.

Comment: What does myRequestRoute do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four different scenarios your routing needs to cover:

1. route must match exact format: site.com/pdf/file.pdf
2. route must match with language before pdf: site.com/en/pdf/file.pdf
3. route must match with anything after pdf: site.com/pdf/aaa/bbb/file.pdf
4. route must match with language before and anything after pdf: site.com/en/pdf/aaa/bbb/file.pdf

The following routes should cover each of the above.

```
global_pdf_1:
class: myRequestRoute
url: /pdf/:filename.pdf
param: { module: location, action: test }
requirements: { sf_method: get }

global_pdf_2:
class: myRequestRoute
url: /pdf/:anything/:filename.pdf
param: { module: location, action: test }
requirements: { sf_method: get, anything: .* }

global_pdf_3:
class: myRequestRoute
url: /:sf_culture/pdf/:filename.pdf
param: { module: location, action: test }
requirements: { sf_method: get }

global_pdf_4:
class: myRequestRoute
url: /:sf_culture/pdf/:anything/:filename.pdf
param: { module: location, action: test }
requirements: { sf_method: get, anything: .* }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your matches should be variables beginning with colon:

```
culture_dir_pdf:
  url: /:sf_culture/pdf/:dirname/:filename.pdf
  param: { module: pdf, action: showEmbed }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }

culture_pdf:
  url: /:sf_culture/pdf/:filename.pdf
  param: { module: pdf, action: showEmbed }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }

global_dir_pdf:
  url: /pdf/:dirname/:filename.pdf
  param: { module: pdf, action: showEmbed }
  requirements: { sf_method: get }

# ...
```

Then you can use those request vars inside your showEmbed action.

If you need advanced matching logic, I would use Apache Rewrite to point PDF requests to a single URL, then you add the URL in your routing.yml.

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Apache 404 - Not Found

The requested URL /pdf/forexbook/en/Forex_Trading_Strategies.pdf was not found on this server.

Comment: Maybe I've mistaken your question. Does the file exist at http:// your-domain/pdf/forexbook/en/Forex_Trading_Strategies.pdf?

Comment: The file does not exist for this urls

Comment: Ok, then besides creating routes for all path levels (/pdf/forexbook/en/Forex_Trading_Strategies.pdf => url: /pdf/:param1/:param2/:filename.pdf), I'd recommend to create an Apache regexp rewrite rule to match all PDF urls that would redirect to a unique symfony route.